# straight lines - slope of perpendicular straight lines

Tags: geometry, slope

Slope of line l (this line is parallel to y-axis) = 1/0.

Slope of line m (this line is parallel to x-axis) = 0.

Line m is perpendicular to line l.

Now, since line 'l' is perpendicular to line 'm'

Therefore, slope of line l × slope of line m = -1.

This implies, 1/0 × 0 = -1

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yyDg.jpg)

Comment: So.  You have a question or what?  You can't divide by 0 and 1/0 is undefined.  You know it.  I know it.  The ducks in the lake begging for bread know it.

Comment: @fleablood Im just asking will that what i have done will be correct.... Im just saying that something which is not defined when multiplied by 0 gives -1 .. How is that possible

Comment: Because it is undefined.  If it is undefined you can't multiply it by anything and have any meaningful answer.  The square root of an elephant is one over an elephant to the negative one half power.  How is that possible.  Because it doesn't mean any thing and it was wrong from the start.  You can't take square roots of elephants, and you can'can't divide by zero.  Whatever happens if you try is meaningless and not true even if it looks correct.  0 = -0 so ax0 = -a x 0.  So a = -a.  So 1= 1/0 x 0 = 1/0 x -0 = -1.  Don't lose sleep over it.  Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @fleablood Ok ur right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope)

"Two lines are parallel if and only if their slopes are equal and they are not the same line (coincident) or if they both are vertical and therefore both have undefined slopes. Two lines are perpendicular if the product of their slopes is −1 or one has a slope of 0 (a horizontal line) and the other has an undefined slope (a vertical line)."

So, it is obvious that the rule of multiplication of slopes is not applied when one of the line is vertical and another horizontal. Further, y-axis (or more specifically, the line x = 0) doesn't have a slope of infinity but it is undefined.

Comment: Thank you for solving my confusion... Thank you very much.

Comment: Mine pleasure to help you.

Comment: You have same question also. So delete that one.

Comment: How to delete please tell me.... I have trying to do so since last 5 min..!!

Comment: Below your question there is delete option. R u tried that?

Comment: I cannot see the deleted button

Comment: Where exactly is it ... Please tell me!!

Comment: Just below your question there are options edit, delete etc.